# Merging two JSON file and reconstructor the JSON by jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I want to use jq tools in shell script to merge two localized json.

Here are the content of files:

**ja:**

```
{
    "link_generate": "ランダム化する",
    "label_apple": "リンゴ"
}
```

**en:**

```
{
    "link_generate": "Randomise",
    "label_apple": "Apple"
}
```

I wanna merge them and create another hierarchy(ja/en) for the duplicate key like:

```
{
    "link_generate": {
        "en": "Randomise",
        "ja": "ランダム化する"
    },
    "label_apple": {
        "en": "Apple",
        "ja": "リンゴ"
    }
}
```

Comment: `ja`, `en` are names of the files?

Comment: The merged output is not valid JSON. Post a syntactically valid one.

Comment: @Inian Yes, it's file name

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```bash
jq -n --slurpfile ja ja.json --slurpfile en en.json '
  [ $en[0] | keys[] | { (.):{ en:$en[0][.], ja:$ja[0][.] } } ] | add'
```

which outputs

```json
{
  "label_apple": {
    "en": "Apple",
    "ja": "リンゴ"
  },
  "link_generate": {
    "en": "Randomise",
    "ja": "ランダム化する"
  }
}
```

Comment: This works well if both languages have the same keyset. However, if `$en` has an entry that is not contained in `$ja`, both languages will still be present for that entry but with `.ja` set to `null`. The other way round, if `$ja` has an entry that is not contained in `$en`, the entry will be omitted entirely. Depending on the actual use case, this may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for an arbitrary number of languages. It uses the first two characters of the filename as language key, and respects an asymmetric population of the dictionaries:

```bash
jq -n 'reduce (inputs | to_entries[] | [input_filename[:2], .])
  as [$lang, $ent] ({}; setpath([$ent.key, $lang]; $ent.value))' ja.json en.json
```

The list of language keys can also be provided separately (hard-coded, or using `--arg` or `--argjson`, and in matching order of the input files):

```bash
jq -n 'reduce (("ja","en") as $lang | input | to_entries[] | [$lang, .])
  as [$lang, $ent] ({}; setpath([$ent.key, $lang]; $ent.value))' ja.json en.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6fOPSmMfBH-)

```json
{
  "link_generate": {
    "ja": "ランダム化する",
    "en": "Randomise"
  },
  "label_apple": {
    "ja": "リンゴ",
    "en": "Apple"
  }
}
```